# Break previous loop inside switchMap()

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's say I have a click observable and then a loop observable:

```
click$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => loop$)
)
.subscribe((x: any) => { 
  console.log(x);
});

loop$ = () => new Observable<any>((subscriber) => {
  for(let i = 0, l = 10000; i < l; i++) {
    subscriber.next(i);
  }
  subscriber.complete();
});
```

As I understand with every new click, switchMap will cancel and resubscribe to the loop$, however it won't really break the previous iteration, right?

Can you please share ideas on how to break the previous loop with every new click?

Thanks!

**Update.**
I'm trying to achieve it like this: the idea is that switchMap() closes the subscription, but just to be sure (and since I can't really imitate consequent click), I have a timeout to complete the subscriber in 1 second... Inside the iteration, we're constantly checking if it was closed and then break. However, it never hits the debugger/break. And the execution order is "Clicked -> false x 5000 -> Complete -> true x 1".

```
this.click$.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Clicked')),
  switchMap(() => this.loop$)
)
.subscribe((x: any) => {
});

loop$ = new Observable<any>((subscriber) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    subscriber.complete();
    console.log('Complete');
    console.log(subscriber.closed);
  }, 1000);
  this.iterate(subscriber);
});

async iterate(subscriber: any): Promise<void> {
  for(let i = 0, l = 5000; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(subscriber.closed);
    if (subscriber.closed) {
      debugger;
      break;
    }
    subscriber.next(i);
  }
  subscriber.complete();
}
```

**Update.** What if I used `setInterval()` without a delay instead of loop?

Comment: Your current loop is entirely synchronous, so it's going to run to completion before it's possible to click again. Are you wanting to have a loop that's spread out in time? And then abort it after only a portion of the time has elapsed?

Comment: @NicholasTower, yes!

Comment: Try to use Subject to emit signal to break the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I managed to achieve it by simply turning 10000 into from(10000), like:

```
this.click$.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Clicked')),
  switchMap(() => from(10000))
)
.subscribe((x: any) => {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const stopLoop$ = new Subject();

click$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => loop$.pipe(takeUntil(stopLoop$)))
)
.subscribe((x: any) => { 
  console.log(x);
});

function loop$(): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable<any>((subscriber) => {
    for(let i = 0, l = 10000; i < l; i++) {
      if (stopLoop$.isStopped) {
        break;
      }
      subscriber.next(i);
    }
    subscriber.complete();
  });
}
```

**switchMap** operator will indeed cancel the previous inner observable and subscribe to a new one whenever a new click occurs. However, the loop inside the loop$ observable is synchronous and runs to completion before emitting values.

whenever a new click occurs, the previous loop will be interrupted, and a new loop will start, preventing the iteration from completing if it's still in progress.

hope it's helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> takeUnitl

```
let subjectInst = null;
click$.pipe(
  subjectInst = new Subject();
  switchMap(() => {
    return loop$.pipe(takeUntil(subjectInst));
 })

)

// On click
click$.subscribe(()=>{
 subjectInst.next();
 subjectInst.complete()
})
```

Hope this helps